# Скульптор, скудельник - этимология

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести существительные "скульптор" и "скудельник" к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 2):

[**Скуде́льница**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-synonyms4-term-132775.htm)

> 1) Широкая и глубокая яма, служившая в старину для погребения умерших
>   от массовых эпидемий, голода и т.п.
>
> 2) Погост или кладбище для массовых захоронений.

[Cловарь архаизмов русского языка](https://archaisms.academic.ru/3529/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

> **Скудельник** - гончар, горшечник

[Орфографічний словник української мови](https://orfograf_ukr.academic.ru/161771/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

> **скуде́льник** - іменник чоловічого роду, істота рідко

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

> **СКУДЕЛЬ**, -и; ж. *Устар.* Глина, глиняный сосуд.
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Этимологический словарь русского языка Макса Фасмера](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/47625/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

> **скуде́ль** ж., род. п. -и "черепица, глиняный сосуд", церк., др.-русск. скудѣль "черепок", скудѣлъ "черепица",ст.-слав. скѫдель
>   κέραμος (Мар., Ассем. и др.), скѫдельникъ κεραμεύς "гончар" (Зогр.,
>   Мар., Ассем., Савв. кн., Рs. Sin.), **скѫдѣльникъ** – то же (Остром.).
>   **Заимств. из лат.**, причем следует иметь в виду преобразование лат.
>   scandula "дранка" по суф. -ella (ср. энгадинск. sk᾽аndеllа "дранка"
>   (М.-Любке 634)); ср. Мейе, Ét. 185; Мi. ЕW 301 и сл. Из близкого
>   источника (лат. scindula) происходит д.-в.-н. scindula "дранка"
>   (Клюге-Гётце 519). •• [Сюда же словен. skodela "миска", сербохорв.
>   зде̏ла – то же.

[Школьный этимологический словарь](https://books.google.ru/books?id=upo6cH_92xcC&pg=PT175&lpg=PT175&dq=%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82.%205%D1%81%D1%86%27%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%A6%D0%B0%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0,%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=CDAoXDUNkL&sig=ACfU3U2e1F18qdcMWmhS80nPWEUQaaj5xQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIuPbNk__gAhUR6aYKHYYEA0UQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Лексика и фразеология севернорусских говоров](https://books.google.ru/books?id=bZglAAAAMAAJ&q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%E2%80%A2%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82&dq=%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%E2%80%A2%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVodvymP_gAhXL-yoKHQtrCWwQ6AEIKDAA)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(А больше не открывается, вот.)

**[СКУЛЬПТОР](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)**

> Происходит от лат. sculptor «резчик, ваятель», sculptura «резьба,
>   ваяние», от гл. sculpere «вырезывать, высекать».

Итого, нисколько скульптор со скудельником не родственники.

Но в утешение есть и немножко псевдонаучного бреда:

> В Толковом словаре русского языка Ушакова, а также в Большой советской
>   энциклопедии и в ряде других источников принято считать, что термин
>   «скульптура» латинского происхождения, и означает – резьба, ваяние.
>
> Однако латинский язык, язык латинов, обнаруживает прямые генетические
>   связи с русским языком образца 15 – 13 веков до н.э. То есть латинский
>   происходит из русского [1, 2, 3 и др.].
>
> В ряде современных языков европейского региона, произошедших во 2 – 1
>   тыс. до н.э. и в 1 тыс. н.э. (например, английский и немецкий) из
>   русского языка, мы находим подтверждения сказанному. В частности,
>   слово «скульптура» в англ. – sculpture, в немец. – Skulptur, во франц.
>   – sculpture. Но в более древнем, итальянском буква «P» не
>   присутствует, и мы уже читаем – scultura. Аналогично в испанском –
>   escultura. Итальянский и испанский языки – потомки латинского.
>
> С (со, су) – древний предлог, пишущийся вместе и означающий
>   расположение или вхождение одного предмета, явления в, рядом, около
>   другого [4](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C). Отсюда становится понятен смысл термина «скульптура» – со
>   + культура, то, что является сопутствующим культу или производным культа: ср. со+путник = спутник (сопутствовать); сукровица
>   (сокровище), сумерки (смеркаться), состав и т.д.
>
> Рассмотрение термина «культ» нас приводит к пониманию сакральной сути
>   скульптуры. По неправильной европейской привычке многие источники
>   указывают происхождение и этого термина – культ – из латинского языка.

Продолжение бреда для мазохистов - см. **[ТУТЪ](http://dazzle.ru/spec/atess.shtml)**.

Comment: сравните: скудельница - рукодельница, скуделя - древоделя

Comment: А зачем мне сравнивать? Ну, один и тот же суффикс; это же не делает корни родными?